# jquery get value from fields in the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get value from each field when I click the button. The result I get is always the first one.

What I expect is that when I click another button it shows a different value. This is my code.

```js
$('.btn').click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 var x = $('.input-class').val();
 alert(x)
})
```

```html
<!-- assume the code inside loop !-->
<tr>
 <td><input type="text" value="1" class="input-class"></td>
 <td>
  <select name="animals" class="animals">
   <option value="cat">Cat</option>
   <option value="tiger">Tiger</option>
   <option value="lion">Lion</option>
  </select>
 </td>
 <td><button class="btn">Click</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td><input type="text" value="2" class="input-class"></td>
 <td>
  <select name="animals" class="animals">
   <option value="cat">Cat</option>
   <option value="tiger">Tiger</option>
   <option value="lion">Lion</option>
  </select>
 </td>
 <td><button class="btn">Click</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td><input type="text" value="3" class="input-class"></td>
 <td>
  <select name="animals" class="animals">
   <option value="cat">Cat</option>
   <option value="tiger">Tiger</option>
   <option value="lion">Lion</option>
  </select>
 </td>
 <td><button class="btn">Click</button></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because calling `val()` on a jQuery object containing multiple elements only reads the value from the first element in the collection.

To achieve what you require you can use DOM traversal to relate the clicked button to its related `input`. In this case using the `this` keyword to reference the element which raised the event along with `prev()` will work:

```js
$('.btn').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var x = $(this).prev().val();
  console.log(x)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="1" class="input-class"> <button class="btn">Click</button>
<input type="text" value="2" class="input-class"> <button class="btn">Click</button>
<input type="text" value="3" class="input-class"> <button class="btn">Click</button>
<input type="text" value="4" class="input-class"> <button class="btn">Click</button>
```

---

*Update:*

Given your update to the HTML in the question, the logic to get the `input` from within the same table row is slightly more complex. You can achieve it instead by using `closest()` to get the nearest common `tr` parent, then `find()`:

```js
$('.btn').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var x = $(this).closest('tr').find('.input-class').val();
  console.log(x)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" value="1" class="input-class"></td>
    <td>
      <select name="animals" class="animals">
        <option value="cat">Cat</option>
        <option value="tiger">Tiger</option>
        <option value="lion">Lion</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td><button class="btn">Click</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" value="2" class="input-class"></td>
    <td>
      <select name="animals" class="animals">
        <option value="cat">Cat</option>
        <option value="tiger">Tiger</option>
        <option value="lion">Lion</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td><button class="btn">Click</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" value="3" class="input-class"></td>
    <td>
      <select name="animals" class="animals">
        <option value="cat">Cat</option>
        <option value="tiger">Tiger</option>
        <option value="lion">Lion</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td><button class="btn">Click</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: it shows all values in array. what i expect when i click secon button it only show value "2"

Comment: Apologies, I misread the intent of your question. I've updated the answer.

Comment: thanks it works in this case. but is there any way that I can use the class? in my real case I have some fields more that I want to pass to the backend

Comment: Possibly, but it depends on exactly what your HTML looks like. I'd suggest editing the question to have an accurate example of it

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I've updated the answer for you

Comment: thanks! it works perfectly

Answer (score -1):

`$('.input-class')` will gather all elements with that class name. maybe you want do a foreach loop and get value from `.input-class` one at a time.